# How to share params variables in child/parent components in Angular2 rc6 without using @Output?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, parameters, angular2-output

I need to access a Params variable sent to a child component in the parent component.

I have the following structure:

Routing: (excerpt)

```
  {
      path: 'song',
      component: SongExerciseComponent,
      children: [
          {
              path: 'reading/:id',
              component: SongReadingComponent,
          }
      ]
  }
```

The parent component is just a template holding navigation links.
I can access the :id var in the child component like so:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.params.forEach((params: Params) => {
      if (params['id'] !== undefined) {
        let id = +params['id'];
```

Now I need the same variable in the parent component to be used in the parent template.

Which is the most effective way to do this? Sharing a service?
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service

Comment: Outputs are fine but they are cumbersome if data should be passed through multiple levels of component hierarchy. A shared service looks like a good match for this case (navigation) to me. A service itself can be an observable or EventEmitter, similarly to output's event emitter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a shared service or use **Ngrx store**, inspired by Redux for Angular2.

There you can read about it - https://gist.github.com/btroncone/a6e4347326749f938510

The advantage of this solution is that you can **subscribe** changes and react on them. Also, data is immutable so you will not change something by mistake. If it is not important for you, just use service.

Comment: Interesting. Didn't know about Ngrx. However I was trying Angular2 to avoid things like Redux, but it seems Angular2 is not there yet - if it will ever be.